Create a new keystore in Visual Studio and connect it to an existing App in my Google Play Console
We had a change with developers and a switch of machines. Now it seams that we lost the connection (certificate/password) to our PlayStore.
What I did:

I started an created a new keystore in Visual Studio.

I still have access to the owner account of the app and I have the
API-Access OAuth keys

The dialog is called "Distribute - Signing Identity", where i created the keystore
with the appropriate data.

I have now an newapp.keystore file.

In the developer account I chose to reset the App Signature.

Now I have 4 options. I chose the 3rd one "to upload a new signature from a java keystore.

I download the public key and the PEPK tool.


Now I am instructed to execute the following command:
$ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=output.zip  --signing-keystore=uploadkey.keystore --signing-key-alias=upload-key-alias --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/path/to/encryption_public_key.pem
And now am confused. I have only my newapp.keystore file created in my 4th step.
This are the questions I have:
What keystore was created by the dialog "Distribute - Signing Identity" in visual studio?
What is the foo.keystore and what is the uploadkey.keystore in the PEPK?
Do I need to create another keystore?
